# What third party devices are air play compatible?

Tags: airplay

At the moment I can play my iTunes library in 2 rooms of my house, from the iMac in the office and through the Apple TV in the lounge. I would like to purchase at least one Airplay compatible device so that music can be streamed into other rooms.

All I have been able to find is the B&W Zepplin Air, which is a bit big and expensive for what I want. Does anyone have any other recomendations?

I am aware that I could do this with the Airport Express, but I would rather have a 1 box solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iHome should be releasing their iW1 soon, which they debuted at CES

[iW1 AirPlay wireless speaker system with rechargeable battery.](http://www.ihomeaudio.com/discover/airplay/)

Comment: Awesome, rechargeable is even better!

Answer (score 0):

To extend your options, you can play music from iTunes through any stereo with bluetooth. I can't find it on google, but I've seen it done.